# Can libzip reliably write in zip archives from buffers/memory (not files)?

Tags: c++, memory, libzip

I am creating an archive dynamically an need to write some binary data dynamically as file entries.
I am also using the *extra_field* API to add more metadata.
Unfortunately when I write using *source_buffer* the data written gets corrupted.

API calls are along the lines of:

```
const std::string diff; //this is initialized and passed from a function
zip_t z_; //class member initialized before
const std::string f; // name of the virtual file, passed in the function
// use unique_ptr to manage the lifetime of zip_source_t
std::unique_ptr<zip_source_t, void (*)(zip_source_t*)>  p_zf(
    zip_source_buffer_create((const void*)diff.data(), diff.size(), 0, 0),
    [](zip_source_t* p) { if(p) zip_source_free(p); }
);
if (!p_zf)
    throw exception ...;
// write inside archive and initialize the fields
const zip_int64_t idx = zip_file_add(z_, f.c_str(), p_zf.get(), ZIP_FL_ENC_GUESS);
if(-1 == idx)
    throw exception ...;
// write extra field
if(zip_file_extra_field_set(z_, idx, FS_ZIP_EXTRA_FIELD_ID, 0, (const zip_uint8_t*)&metadata, sizeof(metadata), ZIP_FL_LOCAL))
    throw exception ...;
```

The code above 'works' but then when I read the archive back for the virtual file `f` I get some garbled values. The metadata (fairly large, 256 bytes) is perfectly stored.

If I replace the *zip_source_buffer_create* with:

```
zip_source_buffer(z_, (const void*)diff.data(), diff.size(), 0)
```

I get the very same garbled data (the size is always as expected, but the content gets *polluted*).
Only if I write a temporary file and then initialize the *zip_source_t* via filesystem API (i.e. *zip_source_file_create*) then all is saved fine:

```
std::unique_ptr<zip_source_t, void (*)(zip_source_t*)>  p_zf(
    zip_source_file_create(tmp_filename, 0, -1, 0),
    [](zip_source_t* p) { if(p) zip_source_close(p); }
);
```

Am I doing anything wrong?
Please note that the lifetime of `diff` is *const* within the scope of both *zip_source_buffer_create*, *zip_source_buffer* and *zip_file_add*.
Is this a potential bug in *libzip*?
I'm using version *1.7.3* on Ubuntu 22.04 64 bit.

Comment: the man page sample uses `zip_source_buffer` not the api you are using https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_file_add.html

Comment: [`zip_source_free` documentation](https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_source_free.html) reads: *NOTE: This function should not be called on a source after it was used successfully in a `zip_open_from_source`, `zip_file_add`, or `zip_file_replace` call.*

Comment: Unfortunately even if I comment out the destructors and/or use zip_source_buffer API, the issue is still there. Also the API doesn't specify the lifetime of the buffers initialized from zip_source_buffer (and similar). For example is zip_file_add to synchronously writing in the ZIP file, thus removing the need for the zip_source_t*? Or instead one should keep the zip_source_t* (and related memory buffers) valid for the whole lifetime of main zip zip_t* zip_open? This would be a crazy requirement...

Comment: I've actually sorted out as per linked question. Looked into the sources of _zip_file_add_ and indeed it doesn't do much with the `zip_source_t` and it will definitely write it upon _zip_close_, which means one has to guarantee the buffer lifetime since then _or_ duplicate the buffer and have it managed by libzip itself. Bad design imho.